# Forbidden access when saving an edited question post using Question2answer script

Tags: web-hosting, 403-forbidden, qa

I installed Question2answer on my paid server. After I published a post/question on my Question2answer site I tried to edit it, but when I was trying to save the post, it outputs an error that says:

> #### Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access 3/theres-music-everywhere on this server

(`3/theres-music-everywhere` is the URL of the post/question)

I thought this was a server problem so I asked the server's support team and they told me that this is a problem with my script and they cannot help me. I also asked on Question2answer platform, and no success at all.  How can I fix this? Editing posts is a very important function.

I'm hosting my Q2A script on [Hostinger.pt](http://Hostinger.pt)  servers (or [hostinger.co.uk](http://hostinger.co.uk) If you prefer I think they are the same.)  I think these are Apache servers not really sure

Comment: This is likely a directory/file permissions issue. I do not know Question2answer. Recheck the install instructions for anything you may have missed. Also stick with their online forum. You can also check the Apache access/error log files for the exact error. This may give more of a clue.

Comment: I searched the web a bit and did not find anything I could link to. Sorry. I invite you to look in your Apache access/error log files for related messages and add them to your question here. With a bit of back and forth, I am sure someone(s) here can solve this for you. But as it stands, there is not enough information to answer your question. We would need more information.

Comment: Hey @closetnoc thanks for the response I went to the 'Error log files' directory in my Cpanel and I hit show logs and it only showed me this: `Bad file!`. Here's what I'm gonna do, there's a thing here on the Cpan that says 'Repair Files Permissions' I'm going to try do that and if still doesn't fix the problem I'll try to make a backup of my files and database and do the "Reload Account" which I think it resets my account as original and then I'll get back to you with the news

Comment: Sounds good to me. If I am not here, this sounds like something that can be fixed by someone who knows Linux.

Comment: I just did the "Reload Account" option and re-installed the script with new fresh database and all, but it's still doing the same thing :\

Comment: I am in chat with someone right now, but your *3/theres-music-everywhere*- is there a directory named 3 or theres-music-everywhere in the web root or software space?

Comment: Do the other pages work fine? It's only when you edit and not when you load the question page? Do you have the htaccess set up?

Comment: Yeah. I was about to ask about the .htaccess file. The software comes with one. If you installed in the root or sub-directory, there my be some adjustment you have to make to that file or your apache2,conf file. Great catch! @DisgruntledGoat It has to be related to .conf, .htaccess, or literal file permissions I suspect.

Comment: Can you post an anonymous (if necessary) copy of any config file and .htaccess file? That would be apache2.conf, any sites-available configuration files that appear to apply, and the .htaccess in the root +/- sub-directory?

Comment: Yeah all the pages seem to be working fine, it's just only on that particular function which is on saving the edit. Here's what's inside my htaccess file: http://jsfiddle.net/chp9qqe6/

Comment: Sorry. I am bouncing around trying to get dinner and to other things... but I did see that your .htaccess is the one from the q2a install which you would think would work. I suspect that there is a conflict somewhere. How about your site config file? You can post it in the question... just remove the domain name and IP address and use example.com and 10.0.0.100 or something similar.

Comment: Check out: http://www.question2answer.org/htaccess.php where it says: *Specifically you want the directive AllowOverride All to be included in the appropriate <Directory> section of your Apache configuration file.* Please check this. If you need help, we are here.

Comment: I tried to remove the "#" and stuff as it says on that page but still couldn't fix it. listen I created a ftp account and an account on the website for testing purposes, could you help me if I give you the credentials to log in?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify your read-write access permissions I am guessing. Log into the server, get the file in question >click click > edit permissions > chmod 644 would probably be the way to go.